# Add two matrices containing NaN in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have two 5D matrices which I would like to add elementwise. The matrices have the exact same dimensions and number of elements, but they both contain randomly distributed NaN values.

I would like to add these two matrices elementwise in an efficient way. I am currently adding them by looping through them elementwise, but this loop takes about 40 minutes and I just thought there must be a more efficient way of doing it.

What I think would be an efficient way is if it was possible to use numpy.nansum to add them, but from what I can find, numpy.nansum only works with 1D arrays.

I would prefer it if the adding went down as it does with numpy.nansum (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html). Namely, (1) if two values are added I want the sum to be a value, (2) if a value and a NaN are added I want the sum to be the value and (3) if two NaN are added I want the sum to be NaN.

Below is an exaplary code:

```
import numpy as np

# Creating fake data
A = np.arange(0,720,1).reshape(2,3,4,5,6)
B = np.arange(720,1440,1).reshape(2,3,4,5,6)

# Assigning some elements as NaN
A[0,1,2,3,4] = np.nan
A[1,2,3,4,5] = np.nan
B[1,2,3,4,5] = np.nan
```

So, if I now add A and B (lets say C = A + B), I want element C[0,1,2,3,4] to be the value of B[0,1,2,3,4], element C[1,2,3,4,5] to be NaN and all other elements in C to be the sums of the respectively added elements in A and B.

Does anyone have an efficient solution for this addition?

Comment: Have you tried masking?  That is, do the usual sum, and then replace the undesired `nan` with the correct values using a masked assignment (boolean index).  It may be require two such steps.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your response! I haven't tried it, but I did consider masking. But what happens when you (i) add one masked value and one real value and (ii) two masked values. What results (sums) are returned for (i) and (ii)?

Comment: I think @hpaulj means add first and afterwards use masking to replace the wrong `nan`s

Comment: Right, well I suppose that would work, but that also sounds to me to require looping through the big matrix and that is what I am trying to avoid as I am already doing that now and it is very time consuming (the real matrices are of the size [2000,200,400]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
np.where(np.isnan(A), B, A + np.nan_to_num(B))
```

We see how this works in two parts:

1. For the nan part of `A`, we fill in values from `B`.

If `B` and `A` are `nan` at the same time, the values stored will be `nan`. If values in `B` are not `nan` while those from `A` are `nan`, the values of `B` will be taken.

2. For the part of `A` that is non-nan, we fill in `A + np.nan_to_num(B)`.

`np.nan_to_num(B)` will turn `B`'s nan part into 0. Thus, `A + np.nan_to_num(B)` will not be `nan` when `B` is `nan`.

Thanks for Paul Panzer's correction.

Comment: `copy=False` doesn't work because `B` is modified before `where` is called, so you'll get `0` in the output where `A` and `B` are both `nan` - apart from that a nice solution

Comment: @PaulPanzer thank you for the correction. Appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you both PaulPanzer and Tai! This also seems like an efficient solution! I am very appreciative!

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking of something more prosaic

```
In [22]: A=np.arange(10.)         # make sure A is float
In [23]: B=np.arange(100,110.)
In [24]: A[[1,3,9]]=np.nan
In [25]: B[[2,5,9]]=np.nan

In [26]: A
Out[26]: array([ 0., nan,  2., nan,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8., nan])
In [27]: B
Out[27]: array([100., 101.,  nan, 103., 104.,  nan, 106., 107., 108.,  nan])
In [29]: C=A+B
In [30]: C
Out[30]: array([100.,  nan,  nan,  nan, 108.,  nan, 112., 114., 116.,  nan])

In [31]: mask1 = np.isnan(A) & ~np.isnan(B)
In [32]: C[mask1] = B[mask1]
In [33]: mask2 = np.isnan(B) & ~np.isnan(A)
In [34]: C[mask2] = A[mask2]
In [35]: C
Out[35]: array([100., 101.,   2., 103., 108.,   5., 112., 114., 116.,  nan])
```

I like the `stack` and `nansum` approach, but I'm not sure it's faster:

```
In [36]: s=np.stack((A,B))
In [37]: C1 = np.nansum(s, axis=0)
In [38]: C1
Out[38]: array([100., 101.,   2., 103., 108.,   5., 112., 114., 116.,   0.])
In [40]: C1[np.all(np.isnan(s), axis=0)] = np.nan
In [41]: C1
Out[41]: array([100., 101.,   2., 103., 108.,   5., 112., 114., 116.,  nan])
```

Look at `s` if this approach is puzzling:

```
In [42]: s
Out[42]: 
array([[  0.,  nan,   2.,  nan,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,  nan],
       [100., 101.,  nan, 103., 104.,  nan, 106., 107., 108.,  nan]])
```

`s` is a new array, with a new 0 dimension.  `sum` on that dimension is the same as `A+B`.  This stacking lets us take advantage of the `nansum`.  Unfortunately you still want to keep some `nan`, so we still have to do a masked assignment to handle that detail.

Comment: Also, since `A` and `B` are apparently large, creating a stacked intermediate may be undesirable.

Comment: Thank you so much for spelling out what you meant! These few lines of code that you just demonstrated, seem very efficient! Just one last question, in your above examples A, B, C, C1 are 1D arrays, but there is no difference in the coding when adding multidimensional arrays with your approaches, correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
s = np.stack((A, B))
C = np.nansum(s, axis=0)
C[np.all(np.isnan(s), axis=0)] = np.nan
```

This will treat `np.nan` as `0.0` for purposes of summing, and then the final line adds back the places where `np.nan` existed for all entries along the new "depth" axis that spans across `A` and `B`.

Note that this last operation is necessary for NumPy versions > 1.8, as it says in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html):

> In NumPy versions <= 1.8.0 Nan is returned for slices that are all-NaN or empty. In later versions zero is returned.

If you can guarantee NumPy version <= 1.8, then just the `nansum` part alone would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new axe before summing :

```
np.nansum(np.concatenate((A[None,:],B[None,:])),axis=0)
```

Comment: Note for NumPy version > 1.8, you need to set the `np.nan` values that would have resulted from summing all `nan` along an axis, since `nansum` treats them as zero. When they're all `nan`, the OP wants the output to be `nan`. Otherwise, to be the sum ignoring the `nan` values.